# selenium android test scripts

Tags: android, selenium, appium

I need to write **selenium test scripts** for an **android app** and test them using **appium**. I have so far written selenium test scripts for web applications where we perform "Inspect Element" to locate web elements and include them in our test scripts. But I have no idea how to **locate the elements** on the **android app** to write test scripts for it. Can anyone please tell me **how to locate elements and write a selenium script for an android app**???

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have Android SDK installed in you machine, please open uiautomatorviewer.bat file from /adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702/sdk/tools and make sure that android app is running on the real device or mobile emulator. In order to start scripting for Mobile automation, you many want to refer the following link:[Appium](http://appium.io/) and [Appium guide](http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?ruby#running-your-test-app-with-appium-(android))